# pdflatex can't compile after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, latex, lyx, hebrew

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, and now I'm in the process of fixing some broken applications :(

My latest problem is with pdflatex (used through Lyx), after upgrading I don't seem to be able to export to PDF, the process fails with the error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `cp1255.def' not found.
LaTeX Error: File `rlbabel.def' not found.
LaTeX Error: File `he8enc.def' not found.
```

I should probably note that the problem arises only when I try to compile documents containing Hebrew which I sometimes use in my documents.

This is really a big deal for me, so help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files seems to be included in `texlive-lang-other`- Install the package and it should work fine.

E.g. `via $ sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-other`

Comment: solved it!
How did you know this is the right package?

Comment: You can search for package content. This can be done with some special apt package or via web using http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: @eladrich it's [`apt-file search`](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm), specifically

Comment: @Glutanimate, does apt-file searches only in packages that I alreay installed?

Comment: @eladrich Nope, it scans the complete repositories. That's why it has to build an index first (with `apt-file update`).

Comment: @Glutanimate, I thought the apt-file update was indexing the installed packages, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I prefer the webinterface ;)